# Delete current row

Tags: vba, ms-access, delete-row

I have a mask tied to a query.

This mask display the records in an access table (one record at a time), say A table.

When the user clicks on a button, the record is copied in another table, say B, and it has to be deleted from the original table (A). Moreover the mask has to pass to the next or previous record, if any.

The table B can't have a key field.

How could I achieve this via vba?

Answer (score 0):

Have your button copy, and then delete the record being displayed on the form on your button press.

```
Sub btnCopy()
    Dim strSQL as string
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TableB SELECT fld1, fld2 FROM TableA WHERE fld1 = '" & txtFld1 & "'"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
    strSQL = "DELETE FROM TableA WHERE fld1 = '" & txtFld1 & "'"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't use the where part. Table A and B are different. The record is transformed in some ways and copied into the B table, then I've to delete the original record from A table, but this record isn't identified by a key. Indeed, the A table contains data imported from an excel file (and the excel file hasn't a "unique" field).

Comment: @Cricket - when you import your data from Excel, you should have a primary key column in the table B using an Autonumber. It doesn't have to be in the Excel file.

Comment: @Cricket You do not have to use a query, you can delete from the form recordset, if by "mask" you mean form. When you delete the current record using a form, you do not need a key, however, having a key is always a good idea.